# Split Array of Dates into Different Arrays by Day

Tags: php

I have an Array of a week with a timestamps like this `2013-01-07 06:55:34` what I would like to do is split the array up to 7 different arrays by the day. Is that possible in PHP?

How I am creating the array is like this

```
$sqlCount="SELECT time_stamp FROM `download_log` WHERE WEEK(`time_stamp`) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND YEAR(`time_stamp`) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$queryCount = mysql_query($sqlCount) or die(mysql_error());


$dates = array();

while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($queryCount))) {
    $dates[] = $row['time_stamp'];
}
```

And what I would like is 7 different arrays like `$monday $tuesday etc.` and each of those arrays have the days from the `$dates` array

Comment: Can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: yup and pretty easy also with a loop and a if... try to do it and post your code, even if it fails, then we can help depure that code and explain what was wrong, it's the best way to learn ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I was very clear on what I wanted but I figured it out this is what I am doing

```
$mon = array();
$tue = array();
$wed = array();
$thur = array();
$fri = array();
$sat = array();
$sun = array();

foreach ($dates as $value) {

if(date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Mon') {
    $mon[] = $value;
    }
    if(date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Tue') {
    $tue[] = $value;
    }
    if(date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Wed') {
    $wed[] = $value;
    }
    if(date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Thu') {
    $thur[] = $value;
    }
    if(date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Fri') {
    $fri[] = $value;
    }
    if(date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Sat') {
    $sat[] = $value;
    }
    if(date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Sun') {
    $sun[] = $value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done with PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and a little bit of looping action.

Something along the lines of the following should get you going:

```
// array to hold all of the dates in
$dates = array('Mon' => array(), 'Tue' => array(), 'Wed' => array(),
               'Thu' => array(), 'Fri' => array(), 'Sat' => array(),
               'Sun' => array());

while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($queryCount))) {
    // get the day of the week for the current element
    $dayOfWeek = date('D', $row['time_stamp']);

    // add the current element to the correct day-entry in the `$dates` array
    $dates[$dayOfWeek][] = $row;
}
```

This is a sample template that can be adapted to use whatever indexes you'd prefer (abbreviated week names, full weeknames, numeric day-of-week, etc). Review the available values from the `date()` function and adjust to whatever suits your needs better.

**EDIT**
I've customized my original/generic `for`-loop above to fit your `while`-loop that's reading from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the built-in [**`WEEKDAY()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function in MySQL?

```
$sqlCount = "SELECT WEEKDAY(`time_stamp`) AS 'weekday', `time_stamp` ...";
```

You can then push the dates like

```
$dates[$row['weekday']][] = $row['time_stamp'];
```

An alternative is the built-in [**`DATE_FORMAT()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. Following use (of the 2nd parameter) will get you abbreviated weekday names.

```
$sqlCount = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%a') AS 'weekday', `time_stamp` ...";
```